# Getting Error while implementing animation to text

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

I am making a chatapp and want to add typerwriter animation when i receive new, but i'm not able to implement that. It animates all the previous text too. I tried using a bool value which will be passed as false when a new message is added to list so that it only animates the text which is set as false and after that it will be set as true. But that is not working either. I hope my problem is clear.

[Image of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w0iI.jpg)

```java
class ChatMessage extends StatelessWidget {
  ChatMessage({super.key, required this.text, required this.isMe,required this.isAnimated});

  final String text;
  final bool isMe;
  bool isAnimated;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: isMe ? MainAxisAlignment.end : MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Visibility(
          visible: isMe ? false : true,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
            child: CircleAvatar(
              child: Icon(Icons.abc),
              radius: 15,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ChatBubble(
          clipper: ChatBubbleClipper5(
              type: isMe ? BubbleType.sendBubble : BubbleType.receiverBubble),
          alignment: isMe ? Alignment.topRight : Alignment.topLeft,
          margin: isMe
              ? EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, right: 10)
              : EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, left: 10),
          backGroundColor: isMe ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey.shade800,
          child: Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
              maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.65,
            ),
            child: isAnimated ? Text(
              text,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15),
            ): AnimatedText(text),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget AnimatedText(String text) {
    return DefaultTextStyle(
      style: GoogleFonts.varelaRound(
        fontSize: 15,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      child: AnimatedTextKit(
        totalRepeatCount: 1,
        animatedTexts: [TypewriterAnimatedText(text)],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add it inside a code block and make your question readable.

Comment: Done, Please check if you can find the solution

Comment: Please also add an image what you want it to look like and how it's looking so I can help.

Comment: i have added the image you can see the type writer animation is getting applied to all the previous messages and i want it for only the new message.